# Sum of closed subsets is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is the following statement correct:

> If $A$ and $B$ are closed subsets of $[0,\infty)$, then $A+B=\{x+y:x \in A,y \in B\}$ is closed in $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: And your steps to proving this?

Comment: Yes it is correct. What do closed subsets look like in your space? It should clear.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel:i did'nt tried it formally with pen & paper,but what i think is the set $A+B$ consists of the sum of elements of sets  $A $ & $B$ .So,$A+B$ equivalent to $A \cup B$,and the union of two closed sets is closed.So,$A+B$ is closed.

Comment: Try it formally. $A + B$ is not equivalent to $A \cup B$. Just take $A = B = [0,1]$.

Comment: Yes. But note that if we replace $[0,\infty)$ with $\mathbb R$ then it's false. E.g. $A=\mathbb Z^+$ and $B=\{-n-1/n: n\in \mathbb Z^+\}.$ Then $0\in \overline {A+B}$  \  $(A+B).$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(c_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ a convergent sequence in $A + B$ with 
$$c := \lim_{n \to \infty} c_n.$$
We need to show, that $c \in A+B$. There exist sequences $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ in $A$ and $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ in $B$ with $c_n = a_n + b_n$. Since $A,B \subseteq [0, \infty)$, we have that $a_n \leq c_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ and since $(c_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ converges it is bounded. Hence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ and $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ are bounded. With the Bolzano Weierstrass theorem we get that there exist convergent subsequences of $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ and $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$. W.l.o.g. we can choose $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ and $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$. Hence there exist 
$$a := \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \quad \text{and} \quad b := \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n.$$
Since $A$ and $B$ are closed, we have $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. Thus it follows that $$c = \lim_{n \to \infty} c_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} (a_n + b_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n + \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = a + b \in A + B.$$ 
I hope that it helps you :)

Answer (score 2):

HINT.-The addition in $\Bbb R$ is continuous (from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R$). You have, for example two ways to prove $A+B$ is closed.

1) If $\{z_n\}$ is a sequence convergent to $z$ and contained in $A+B$ then $z\in A+B$.

2) The complement of $A+B$ is easily proved to be open (using also the continuity of the sum of reals).

There are more (for example the adherence of $A+B$ is equal to $A+B$).